# multiple authors and subtitles in Rmarkdown yaml

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to follow [this pandoc example](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html#yaml-metadata-block) to add multiple authors to an Rmarkdown file in the [yaml metadata block](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#yaml-metadata-block). The pdf will generate in RStudio (Version 0.98.932), but there is no author information.

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
author:
- name: Author One
  affiliation: University of Somewhere
- name: Author Two
  affiliation: University of Nowhere
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
tags: [nothing, nothingness]
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

  It consists of two paragraphs.
output: pdf_document
---
```

I'd also like to customize the heading a bit more and add a subtitle. Possible?

Comment: Try to remove the dashes -. And make sure your using ```\t``` For me it works like that

Comment: Where are you putting the `\t`?

Comment: Ooh i am sorry, i removed the second author for testing forgot about it. It is not possible to call a author key twice. So therefor you can do something like this "Name1 & Name2". Also affiliation is a not known parameter to the newest yaml i believe.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The default latex template in rmarkdown does not support author affiliations or subtitles. It does support multiple authors however, the correct yaml syntax is

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
author:
- Author One
- Author Two
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
tags: [nothing, nothingness]
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

  It consists of two paragraphs.
output: 
    pdf_document:
        template: NULL
---
```

If you want to customize your header, the best approach is to modify the latex template, [found here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex) to suit your needs. Then copy it to your local directory and pass it to the header in the `template` field.

Comment: Doesn't seem to support abstract, as mentioned here.

Comment: This answer is not correct in that yaml does support subtitles! See below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33680803/5124002).

Comment: This answer is not correct in that yaml does support subtitles, and you can add standard LaTeX syntax for the affiliations if your output is in PDF. See below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777804/4434088

Answer (score 70):

I just found out that it is possible to add subtitles to R markdown PDF output. I am using R 3.2.2 and RStudio 0.99.473 in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
subtitle: 'This is the subtitle'
output: pdf_document
---
```

Answer (score 22):

As explained in the main answer, the default R Markdown template does not support author affiliations. While users can edit the template file to add their own custom YAML fields, there are easier some workarounds you can use for PDF or HTML outputs.

### HTML Outputs

You can use the recently released [radix template](https://rstudio.github.io/radix/basics.html). First you must install the package:

```
install.packages("radix")
```

Once installed, you must set the

```
---
title: "Radix for R Markdown"
description: | 
  Scientific and technical writing, native to the web
date: May 4, 2018
author:
  - name: "JJ Allaire"
    url: https://github.com/jjallaire
    affiliation: RStudio
    affiliation_url: https://www.rstudio.com
  - name: "Rich Iannone"
    url: https://github.com/rich-iannone
    affiliation: RStudio
    affiliation_url: https://www.rstudio.com
output: radix::radix_article
---

Your content
```

[image]

### PDF Outputs

You can use premade templates, and there are some good examples within the **rticles** package. First we must install the package:

```
install.packages("rticles")
```

Once Installed, you can use one of the templates, such as the Journal of Statistical Software:

```
---
author:
  - name: FirstName LastName
    affiliation: University/Company
    address: >
      First line
      Second line
    email: \email{name@company.com}
    url: http://rstudio.com
  - name: Second Author
    affiliation: Affiliation
title:
  formatted: "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package \\pkg{foo}"
  # If you use tex in the formatted title, also supply version without
  plain:     "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package foo"
  # For running headers, if needed
  short:     "\\pkg{foo}: A Capitalized Title"
abstract: >
  The abstract of the article.
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [keywords, not capitalized, "\\proglang{Java}"]
  plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, Java]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
output: rticles::jss_article
---
```

[image]

Comment: The PDF for this no longer knits - if I copy this, I get the error message:

`! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \Plainauthor
                 {FirstName LastName, Second Author} 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile PDF.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See PDF.log for more info.
`Execution halted

Any idea why?

Answer (score 15):

If you render a pdf, LaTex use authors' footnote for affiliations (i.e. converting numbering in symbles). Try

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
subtitle: 'This is the subtitle'
author:
- Author One^[University of Somewhere]
- Author Two^[University of Nowhere]
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
tags: [nothing, nothingness]
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

  It consists of two paragraphs.
output: pdf_document
---
```

Comment: To those wondering how to add authors with the same affiliations: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61304/144923

Answer (score 9):

I've found a solution to your subtitle part of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444545/14027216

You can add subtitle by adding `subtitle:` to your code and multiple subtitles can be added as follow:

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
subtitle: |
  | 'subtitle 1'
  | 'subtitle 2'
author:
- name: Author One
  affiliation: University of Somewhere
- name: Author Two
  affiliation: University of Nowhere
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
tags: [nothing, nothingness]
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

  It consists of two paragraphs.
output: pdf_document
---
```

You can add more than two subtitles, but I don't know the maximum amount. Each subtitle will be displayed in new line.

Answer (score 7):

I've also had this problem. Following the suggestion from @tmpname12345 I modified the latex template (default.tex) and the html template (default.html) to render subtitles. This pull request is on github [rstudio/rmarkdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/pull/374) if you want the code quickly, and looks like it will be standard in rmarkdown next time they push to CRAN.

Answer (score 7):

Add to the answer by Ze Grisi, i just discovered adding html heading tags into the yaml works to adjust the font in the title and subtitle. Note the quotation marks are no longer needed.

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
subtitle: <h1>This is the subtitle</h1>
output: pdf_document
---
```

For a more dramatic effect add an underline to the subtitle

```
---
title:  'This is the title: it contains a colon'
subtitle: <h1><u>This is the subtitle</u></h1>
output: pdf_document
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a solution for latex here [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214404/add-affiliations-to-the-authors-name-in-the-article-class) by @greg. I put the latex code into **rmarkdown yaml header** *with some changes* and it does the job.

```
---
title: 'Some Title'
author: Author One$^1$ \and 
        Author Two$^2$ \and
        Author Three$^3$ 
date: $^1$Organization 1 \newline
      $^2$Organization 2 \newline
      $^3$Organization 3 
    \newline  
    \newline
    \today 
output: 
---
```

The trick is to put the affiliations into **date** tag.

Comment: It is tested only in pdf output!