# R markdown doesn't knit author name in pdf

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

I am writing a document in r markdown. When I knit it to pdf, instead of the author name the pdf simply displays "true.

The knitting works perfectly well with html outputs, besides it seems to me it should work.

```r
---
title: "knitr will you work please?"
author:
  name: John Smith
output: pdf_document
---
```

The output will display

```
knitr will you work please?
true
```

and not

```
knitr will you work please?
John Smith
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this works in HTML but not PDF. One fix is to use `author: "John Smith"`.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043807/multiple-authors-and-subtitles-in-rmarkdown-yaml and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918716/authors-and-affiliations-in-the-yaml-of-rmarkdown

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
---
title: "knitr will you work please?"
author: John Smith
output: pdf_document
---
```