# Knitting to pdf, add a subtitle R

Tags: r

Need to add a subtitle.
In r code, the name of the subtitle is course name, but it doesn't appear on pdf output when I knit it.

How to add a course name subtitle?

[R code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpGCg.jpg)

[pdf slide output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVioy.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043807/multiple-authors-and-subtitles-in-rmarkdown-yaml

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, taycants! For this and your previous question, consider this: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.